# How do I detect if a JMS instance is up in a jboss cluster

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jndi

I have a clustered jboss environment and some JMS queues in it. 
I only want one instance of the Queue to run at one time.
I am new to JMS API. Can I write some code to detect JMS instances running in the cluster to achieve this?
I have seen code to find if a queue exists via JNDi lookup, but I think it only looks up the server's JVM and not the entire cluster. Please advise.

Thanks!
Aniruddh